# How to get Http response of requested JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using jQuery.ajax( {
        url :some.json,
        type :"GET",
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
        success :function(data){

```
    }
    ,error:function(jqXHR,text,error){
        alert(jqXHR.status);
                    alert(jqXHR.statusText);
                    alert(jqXHR.readyState);
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);

    }
    ,beforeSend:function(){   }
    ,complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){

        alert(jqXHR.status);
                    alert(jqXHR.statusText);
                    alert(jqXHR.readyState);
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);

    }



});
```

In above ajax call if any thing went wrong like server problem or json url wrong, i want to show error message, for that i need http response codes like 500, 404.. but i tried with all ways, which you can see in alerts of above code, every time i will get 200 if it is success other wise it is giving 0 instead of actual http response code (if any problems like server error or json url wrong, but i am unable to get actual http response codes).i have worked on this hole day still i am unable to get proper solution. i am using ajax version 1.5.2. can any body please tell EXACT ANSWER for this, as it is very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (From jQuery docs):

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.